# HTTP POST from Classic ASP to WCF REST Service

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, rest, asp-classic

I have a website that has legacy, classic ASP code. This website has a number of forms, but when a user clicks on the submit button, it should only post input from two forms and not anything more. Furthermore, I made a WCF REST service that responds to HTTP POST requests and returns XML. If I try to HTTP POST with my current code, content from all input fields is combined and sent via HTTP POST. This is not what I want. It should be just a simple XML that I myself generate and send it further to my REST service, which afterwards returns a text string telling me, whether it was successful request or not. How do I do this? I tried to search both Google and SO, but there was nothing really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want your form to submit to another page that you control and where you construct the XML.  Once you have created the payload you will want to use the ServerXMLHTTP object something like below.

```
set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")    
xmlhttp.open "POST", url, false ' usage xmlhttp.open method, url, async
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"    
xmlhttp.send payload ' The payload variable containing the XML
responsetxt =  xmlhttp.responseText 
httpstatus = xmlhttp.status 
statustext = xmlhttp.statustext
set xmlhttp = nothing
```

Afterwards you will need to check the httpstatus to see if it succeeded (httpstatus=200) and what the contents of the responsetxt is.